# Read a file continuously and sending the output to another file

Tags: python, file, line

I have a file 'out.txt' that is updated continuously. I need to send the contents of this file periodically to another file 'received.txt' every N minutes.  I do not want the previous lines to be sent. So the scripts needs to send the new data and update 'received.txt' with the new lines of txt, but not repeat lines.

I'm having a hard time putting this script together. I'm guessing I need some sort of loop to do this continuously. Here is what I have so far. (not in order)

EDIT: I am using Debian(Raspbian) on a Raspberry Pi

```
import sys

num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('out.txt')) # read the last line of the updated file

sys.stdout = open('received.txt', 'w')  #write to the received.txt file
print 'test'

f = open('out.txt', 'r') #read the data from the last line
f.readline(num_lines)
for line in f:
    print line
```

Any advice would be extremely helpful.
Thank you

Comment: Watch out - you got curly quotes in your code. Those can cause some major headaches if you don't notice them.

Comment: What platform are you on? The different options are different for each platform.

Comment: Sorry, I am using Rasbian on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

The simplest is to keep looping over the file even after EOF. You could do this by just wrapping a `while True:` around the `for line in f:`, or by just looping forever around `f.readline()`.

But this will waste a lot of CPU power and possibly even disk access checking over and over as fast as possible whether the file is still at EOF. You can fix that by sleeping whenever you get to the end of the file, like this:

```
while True:
    for line in f:
        print line
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

But if the file is not written to for a long time, you're still wasting CPU power (which may not seem like a problem, but imagine what happens when the computer wants to go to sleep, and it can't because you're making it work every half a second). And meanwhile, if the file is being written to a lot faster than twice/second, you're going to lag.

So, a better solution is to block until there's something to read.

Unfortunately, there's no easy cross-platform way to do this. Fortunately, there are relatively easy platform-specific ways to do it on most platforms, but I'd need to know your platform to help.

For example, on OS X or other *BSD systems, you can use [`kqueue`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/select.html#select.kqueue) to wait until a file has something to read:

```
from select import *

# the rest of your code until the reading loop

while True:
    for line in f:
        print line
    kq = kqueue()
    kq.control([kevent(f.fileno(), filter=KQ_FILTER_READ, flags=KQ_EV_ADD)], 0, 0)
    kq.control(None, 1)
    kq.close()
```

But that won't work on Windows, or linux, or any other platform. (Also, that's a pretty bad way to do it on BSD, it's just shorter to show this way than the right way. If you want to do this for OS X, find a good tutorial on using `kqueue` in Python, don't copy this code.)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Are you sure yours doesn't work? I didn't originally notice that he was only expecting the file to be updated every N minutes, and on a pretty fixed schedule to boot, so as long as a lag of up to N minutes is acceptable—which it probably is—your `sleep` solution should be fine. Also, writing the whole thing at once (or, if the files are huge, maybe chunk by chunk) may be better than going line by line for the OP's use case.